# New to algorithms, where to begin?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, algorithm

I have been struggling as to where to begin learning algorithms because of the insane amount of information out there. I don't have any knowledge on algorithms other than solving a Rubik's cube. I'm wondering what is a good source for a beginner to learn algorithms and if they're useful. I should also mention that the languages I know are PHP, Javascript and MySQL.

Comment: High school math class is a good place to start although you started learning algorithms when you added your first two numbers together. There are algorithms for a broad range of.... *everything*.

Comment: [There's a stackexchange site for this sort of question.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @JayBlanchard From my very basic understanding of algorithms, all they are is algebra. Am I correct?

Comment: @JoeScotto that's *sometimes* true, but you can't really describe the process of sorting a list of numbers with algebraic rules.

Comment: let's say, _how to get a girl in 5 steps_ is also an algorithm.

Comment: I know that algorithms are just a series of steps but I don't know the specifics of how to write them. That's what I need, a source that will teach me how to code algs.

Comment: Let's say music's *circle of fifths* is an algorithm.

Comment: @JoeScotto, to understand algorithms you need a problem to solve.  The algorithm is simply the code that you have to write to solve the problem.

Comment: Look at the actual definition of algorithm. Your morning routine could be described as algorithmic.

Comment: @jbarker2160 So basically the code I'm writing already are algorithms?

Comment: @JoeScotto, yes.  An algorithm is simply the steps required to accomplish something.  If you already have working programs you already write working algorithms!  Are you impressed with yourself??

Comment: @jbarker2160 What about when you see something such as "O(n)"? What does that mean and how would you code it?

Comment: Just to give you some idea of the range of different algorithms for all manner of problems - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms

Comment: O(n) (aka [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) isn't an algorithm, it's not something that you code: it's a measure of the "cost" of an algorithm

Comment: So, all I really need to do is just keep coding and solving problems the way I'm used to?

Comment: A great place to start is to get [The Book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) on the subject.

Comment: http://algorithms.openmymind.net/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upvote for wanting someting to learn and actually asking.

As @jbarker2160 wrote: Computer-programs are algorithms. If you know MySQLs SQL dialect you might run into the `PROCEDURE` command. A good example for that.

If you read about Computer history you will soon learn that some early computer programs were nothing else than a series of switch-combinations (on/off) represented by little holes in a paper. Modern programming languages like JavaScript are a high-level abstraction from that "binary" code but deep in their core they still just talk "on" and "off".

Good luck with your programming!